# FBSDKHashtag not attached in FBSDKShareDialogMode.FeedBrowser

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I could not attach a hashtag when using the `.FeedBrowser` share dialog mode. I have no problem when using `.Native` mode, but I needed a fallback in case a native app is not installed. Here's the code I'm using:

```
let shareContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
shareContent.hashtag = FBSDKHashtag(string: "#MyHashtag")
shareContent.contentURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2vj7O1XEEg")
let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
dialog.fromViewController = viewController
dialog.shareContent = shareContent
dialog.mode = .Native
dialog.delegate = self
if !dialog.canShow() {
  dialog.mode = .FeedBrowser
}
dialog.show()
```

I couldn't find any information in Facebook's documentation regarding this. Can anyone tell me if I'm missing something here?

Comment: This seems fixed with the latest Facebook iOS SDK (v4.15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the Facebook SDK for iOS (v4.15), and the issue seems fixed.